# Identify this succulent/echevaria?

Tags: identification, succulents, poisons

Can anyone precisely identify this plant?

[image]

The pot just says "Echeveria." As you can see there are cat-tooth marks on the plant, but I had left it out because I thought echeveria to be [non-toxic to pets](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/cats-plant-list). However, my cat is now sick and I am working with the vet to identify possible causes. Does anyone know the precise identity of this plant? Is it a danger to cats? (I have moved the plant out of the way for the time being.)

Comment: How is your cat?

Comment: @Escoce: Recovering nicely, thanks for asking! It turns out it was a case of pancreatitis. I'm thankful it was both treatable and not my fault :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well its definitely an Echeveria - as to which one, there are thousands, so can't say for sure. None of this group of plants is poisonous to cats though - if you have a Jade plant (Crassula species) that is toxic to them. They look a little similar, but Echeveria has those points on the leaves that aren't present on Crassula ovata or C. portulaca, and the colour of the leaves is different, not being this bluish grey colour.

Comment: Variety isn't important if they're all equally non-toxic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a small crassulaceae. Very toxic and just for humans can cause a very bad rash just by touch. Wouldn't doubt that it got your cat sick after nibbling on the leaf.